# Conditional selecting of list elements

Tags: python, python-docx

I want to extract both survey questions and survey items (which are formatted with header 2 and header 3 respectively, from a word document.

After importing and reading all paragraphs of a word document with the docx module into python, I encounter the following problem when having all paragraphs in a total list:

When there is a subset of list elements (in this case, all list elements which are formatted as "header 3") I want to add all these elements with this formatting into a distinctive list **until** there is a paragraph is not formatted with "header 3".

If there is another occurence of another subset of list elements with "header 3" I want to add them to a different list.

I have already created a dictionary with the keys being the survey questions and the values being an empty list which needs to be replaced by the individual lists of items.

```
import docx
import random
import string

doc = docx.Document('test2.docx')

all_paras = doc.paragraphs


questions = []
items = []
questions_and_items = {}
items_group = []

# questions#

for paragraph in all_paras:
    if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading 2'): 
        questions.append(paragraph.text)

# answer items#

for paragraph in all_paras:
    if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading 3'):
        items.append(paragraph.text)

# prepare keys of list

for question in questions:
    questions_and_items[question] = []
```

My question is now: What is the best way to extract the relevant, suitable sublist of elements which relate to the certain questions and add them to the suitable key in the dictionary?

Comment: Hi. Please add example of `all_paras`. And also example of expected results may be helpful.

Comment: It's especially important to provide sample input when asking questions here. That would be easier if you posted a simpler [mre] illustrating what you want to do (i.e. one that didn't use the third-party `docx` module).

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a single loop through the paragraphs, adding q/a combinations as you go.

```py
import docx

def get_q_a(paragraphs, is_question, is_answer):
    question = None
    answers = []
    q_and_a = {}
    for paragraph in paragraphs:
        if is_question(paragraph):
            if question is not None:
                q_and_a[question] = answers
            question = paragraph
            answers = []
        elif is_answer(paragraph):
            answers.append(paragraph)
    if question is not None:
        q_and_a[question] = answers
    return q_and_a

if __name__ == '__main__':
   doc = docx.Document('test2.docx')
   print(get_q_a(doc.paragraphs,
                 lambda p: p.style.name.startswith('Heading 2'),
                 lambda p: p.style.name.startswith('Heading 3')))
```